# garbage value in byte array in JNA

Tags: java, arrays, c, jna

I am writing a sample C program just to print the input parameters passed to the program from Java using JNA. The C prog has to take unsigned char * as input.
My C prog is like

```
void foo(unsigned char * inp){
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("data received is %s\n",inp);
    printf("The size is %d \n",strlen(inp));
}
```

In Java
I am calling the function using a byte array

```
/* load library*/
libPGM=loadLibrary(); // user defined function to load C library
    
String str = "Abcdefg";
byte[] byteArr = str.getBytes();
System.out.println("byte length is :"+byteArr.length);
String str_2=new String(byteArr);
System.out.println("Inside the java pgm "+str_2);

libPGM.foo(byteArr);
```

This is the output I am getting

```
[stdout] (default task-1) byte length is :7
[stdout] (default task-1) Inside the java pgm Abcdefg

data received is Abcdefg?�$��
The size is 12
```

I am not getting why this is happening.
Why I am seeing the garbage value and why the length has increased??

If I pass a string instead of byte array it is working fine, but in the original C prog, the string needs to overwritten and thus I can't pass the String parameter as input.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks I am getting the answer following the link. Though I have a small doubt, that if that procedure can be done without initializing another array and copying the values, because the size for the arrays could be larger. Something like just appending a 0 at the end of the array.

Comment: The problem with your proposal is the byte length is fixed when you use the `getBytes()` method.  But if you append the `\0` character to your string before you call `getBytes()` it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Your native code is assuming the array is a null terminated string. But Java does not null terminate strings. And byte arrays can't be null terminated because a 0 byte is a valid value.

Comment: I am also thinking the same. Is there something else which I can do ? Like using a pointer reference will work out or not?

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain If you're using a byte array, make it one byte bigger and set the byte to zero.   You can also use JNA's `Memory` class to declare native memory, set the String (or byte array) in the first N bytes and set the last byte to 0.